# Doxygen -> Doxy2Swig -> pdoc results in duplicate class docstrings

Tags: python, c++, doxygen, swig, pdoc

I have a C++ header file (.h) that (through swig) I generate a python module for. My goal is to include the Doxygen documentation from the .h file in the generated .py file, but since I am currently unable to use the latest swig (v4+) that supports this through swig, I am using Doxygen and doxy2swig to accomplish this.

My process is as follows:

- run Doxygen on .h file to generate xml output
- run doxy2swig on xml output to generate a .i file with %docstring insertion
- update my project's .i file
- run swig on .h file (with a .i file that includes the doxy2swig generated .i file)
- run pdoc on generated .py file to generate interface documentation

I've found that doxy2swig inserts docstrings in both the class and `__init__` docstrings, and pdoc concatenates these in the generated documentation, resulting in duplicate descriptions.

I am looking for a way to do one of the following:

- force doxy2swig to only insert docstrings in class OR _*init*
- force pdoc to ignore class or `__init__`

This I have tried/looked into:

- `__pdoc__[class.__init__]` = False. This didn't work, and even if it did it would mean adding all of my classes to this dict.
- manually modified the doxy2swig generated .i file to append docstring to class.**init** instead of class. This was an invalid format.
- Couldn't find any pdoc or doxy2swig arguments that would help me with this - was hoping for something similar to the sphinx options that I believe exist for excluding class documentation from generated docs, or something to exclude the `__init__` doctoring.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify [pdoc's HTML template](https://pdoc.dev/docs/pdoc.html#edit-pdocs-html-template) to accomplish what you are looking for. Here are some examples for a custom `module.html.jinja2`:

Hide docstrings for `__init__`:

```
{% extends "default/module.html.jinja2" %}
{% macro docstring(var) %}
    {% if var.name != "__init__" %}
        {{ default_docstring(var) }}
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Hide class-level docstrings:

```
{% extends "default/module.html.jinja2" %}
{% macro docstring(var) %}
    {% if var.type != "class" %}
        {{ default_docstring(var) }}
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Hide `__init__` entirely:

```
{% extends "default/module.html.jinja2" %}
{% macro is_public(doc) %}
    {% if doc.name != "__init__" %}
        {{ default_is_public(doc) }}
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```